# How to add an ActionBar to a PreferenceScreen?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat, preferencescreen

I have just migrated from `ActionBarSherlock` and I also had to increase the minSDK to 14. I am trying to make it look like the way it was. (I am not interested in the material design guidelines for **now**. My **priority** for **now** is to make it as similar as possible to the previous version.)
One of the problems I am facing right now is related to `PreferenceActivity`.

I made the `ActionBar` visible by using `AppCompatPreferenceActivity` but as soon as I click a `PreferenceScreen`, it shows that `PreferenceScreen` on it's own and it loses the `ActionBar`.

I know there are many questions related to showing the title/`ActionBar` on `PreferenceActivity`. My question is different, I am curious about the title/`ActionBar` of `PreferenceScreen`(s) when they are opened through an `AppCompatPreferenceActivity`.

Any ideas?